# DISCORD.PY : I want to move all members to a specific channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@bot.command()
async def movienight(ctx, member: discord.Member, channel: discord.VoiceChannel):
  await member.move_to(channel)
```

MY SUFFIX FOR COMMANDS IS !tpl

if i write on discord
!tpl movienight "@member" "channelsname"   -   then this works and move @member1 to the CHANNELS NAME I WROTE

But i want to make the command look like -> !tpl movienight

so it will move everyone connected to another channel to the GENERAL without asking for a @member or for a channels name

Comment: What have you tried and why doesn't it work?

Comment: I've tried removing the parameter "channel" on the function and putting 
@bot.command()
async def movienight(ctx, member: discord.Member):
  await member.move_to("i've tried: ID, CHANNELS NAME")
and it doesnt let go through, what i wanna know is what parameter does the member.move_to can receive

Comment: [`move_to`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20member#discord.Member.move_to) accepts [`VoiceChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20member#discord.VoiceChannel) or [`StageChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20member#discord.StageChannel) as the channel. Try doing this 
`await member.move_to(bot.get_channel(channel_id))`. Remember that `channel_id` must be an `int` value

Comment: `@bot.command()
async def movienight(ctx, member : discord.Member):
  
  channel = discord.channel.VoiceChannel
  channel.id = "id"
  await member.move_to(channel)
  `

ive just done this and it works, only asks for a @member and it moves it to the channel i want ("id").  What i need is to move everyone connected to one channel to the one i want

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
async def movienight(ctx, initial_channel_id: int, move_to_channel_id: int):
   # Get the channels
   initial_channel = discord.utils.get(bot.channels, id=initial_channel_id)
   move_to_channel = discord.utils.get(bot.channels, id=initial_channel_id)
   
   # Check if the channel types are valid
   if not isinstance(initial_channel, (discord.VoiceChannel, discord.StageChannel)):
      await ctx.send('Invalid ID for `initial_channel_id`')
      return
   if not isinstance(move_to_channel, (discord.VoiceChannel, discord.StageChannel)):
      await ctx.send('Invalid ID for `move_to_channel_id`')
      return

   # Move all the members:
   for member in initial_channel.members:
      try:
         member.move_to(move_to_channel, reason='Provide your reason here - optional')
      except discord.Forbidden:
         await ctx.send(f'Trying to move {member} failed')
      else:
         await ctx.send(f'Successfully moved {member}')

   await ctx.send(f'Moved all members from {initial_channel.mention} to {move_to_channel.mention}')
```

The way you have written the code will give you unnecessary warnings and errors. Since you want to move every member from the initial voice channel, providing a `member` argument is not required.

`initial_channel_id` stands for the id of the voice/stage channel where the members originally are, and, `move_to_channel_id` stands for the id of the voice/stage channel you would like to move the members to.